# R: dataframe split and order column according to another column

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, split

The title might seem a little bit confusing, so let me see if I can clarify with a small example:

I have a data frame with 3 columns looking like this

```
   col1     col2     col3
1 A,D,C sd,dg,ds   5,26,1
2   D,F    fh,we    85,41
3     H       hr       27
4 C,A,D ds,sd,dg 235,65,3
5 Q,G,J rt,gh,we 34,98,65
```

I want to order each element of col1 alphabetically, and then order each element of col2 and col3 according to the order in col1, to get this:

```
   col1     col2     col3
1 A,C,D sd,ds,dg   5,1,26
2   D,F    fh,we    85,41
3     H       hr       27
4 A,C,D sd,ds,dg 65,235,3
5 G,J,Q gh,we,rt 98,65,34
```

It is important cause later on I want to aggregate by col1, and I need elements 1 and 4 in the example to be equal (A,C,D)

So far I am stuck here:

MWE

```
my.df <- data.frame(col1=c('A,D,C','D,F','H','C,A,D','Q,G,J'), col2=c('sd,dg,ds','fh,we','hr','ds,sd,dg','rt,gh,we'), col3=c('5,26,1','85,41','27','235,65,3','34,98,65'))
my.df
my.df$col1 <- sapply(sapply(strsplit(as.character(my.df$col1), ','), sort), paste, collapse=',')
my.df
```

Any help appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn each row into a data frame, reorder the data.frame based on the column 1, then paste it all back together:

```
# split the entries by commas and
# turn each row of my.df into a data frame
# storing each data frame in a list element
dfList <- lapply(
  apply(my.df, 1, strsplit, ","),
  function(x) data.frame(x))

# sort each data frame by col1
dfSortedList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) x[with(x, order(col1)), ])

# paste columns back together and arrange as desired
t(sapply(dfSortedList, function(x) apply(x, 2, paste, collapse = ",")))

#     col1    col2       col3      
#[1,] "A,C,D" "sd,ds,dg" "5,1,26"  
#[2,] "D,F"   "fh,we"    "85,41"   
#[3,] "H"     "hr"       "27"      
#[4,] "A,C,D" "sd,ds,dg" "65,235,3"
#[5,] "G,J,Q" "gh,we,rt" "98,65,34"
```

You can convert back to a data frame if necessary.

Comment: Really elegant, better avoiding a loop!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
my.df <- data.frame(col1=c('A,D,C','D,F','H','C,A,D','Q,G,J'), col2=c('sd,dg,ds','fh,we','hr','ds,sd,dg','rt,gh,we'), col3=c('5,26,1','85,41','27','235,65,3','34,98,65'),stringsAsFactors = F)

for (k in 1:dim(my.df)[1]){
    tempdf <- data.frame(strsplit(my.df[k,1],","),strsplit(my.df[k,2],","),strsplit(my.df[k,3],","),stringsAsFactors = F)
    tempdf <- tempdf[order(tempdf[,1]),]
    my.df[k,] <- sapply(tempdf,paste,collapse=",")
}
```

As you can see, I went converting each row into a temporary data frame by separating the character strings by the commas. Then you only need to order the temporary data frame by the first column. And from there you collapse each column of tempdf into a string and replace it in the original my.df

Result:

```
> my.df
   col1     col2     col3
1 A,C,D sd,ds,dg   5,1,26
2   D,F    fh,we    85,41
3     H       hr       27
4 A,C,D sd,ds,dg 65,235,3
5 G,J,Q gh,we,rt 98,65,34
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and `data.table`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
na.omit(cSplit(setDT(my.df, keep.rownames=TRUE), 2:4, ",","long"))[
        , {i1 <- order(col1)
         lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x[i1], collapse=","))
     }, rn][, rn:= NULL][]
#   col1     col2     col3
#1: A,C,D sd,ds,dg   5,1,26
#2:   D,F    fh,we    85,41
#3:     H       hr       27
#4: A,C,D sd,ds,dg 65,235,3
#5: G,J,Q gh,we,rt 98,65,34
```

---

Or a slightly lengthier option would to  split the 'col1' and convert the dataset to 'long' format with `cSplit`, then grouped by 'col2' and 'col3', we create an `order` column ('i1') and `sort`ed 'col1'.  Then, specify `.SDcols` as 'col2' and 'col3', loop over those with `lapply`, split the columns using `,`, change the `order` based on the 'i1' column with `Map`, `paste` it together and assign (`:=`) the output back to the original columns.  If needed, assign the 'i1' to NULL.

```
d1 <- cSplit(my.df, "col1", ",", "long")[, 
 .(i1 = list(order(col1)), col1 = toString(sort(col1))) ,.(col2, col3)]
d1[,  c('col2', 'col3') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
  Map(function(x, y) x[y], strsplit(as.character(x), ","), d1$i1)), .SDcols = col2:col3]
d1[, i1:= NULL]
d1[, names(my.df), with = FALSE]
#     col1     col2     col3
#1: A, C, D sd,ds,dg   5,1,26
#2:    D, F    fh,we    85,41
#3:       H       hr       27
#4: A, C, D sd,ds,dg 65,235,3
#5: G, J, Q gh,we,rt 98,65,34
```